# What is doing this?

Tags: files, chmod, lock

When I try to download new software or update (in terminal) I get these errors...

```
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - setupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not lock the file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

This is driving me crazy!  Any help would be much appreciated.  I am new to Linux.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: 2 things: it is custom to provide the command leading to a notice. And the last line seems pretty informative. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/764730/w-chmod-0700-of-directory-var-lib-apt-lists-partial-failed-setupaptpartialdi  or http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process "sudo" is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To run an operation such as `apt-get update` or `apt-get install`, or even something with `dpkg -i` etc (I assume you are running one of these or similar), you need to use `sudo` and run the commands with root privileges. For security reasons normal users do not have such privileges but can use root to gain them for the purpose of executing a certain command.

To run a command with `sudo` simply place it at the beginning like this for instance:

```
sudo apt-get update
```